# What is the severity level of the error when a table is missing in SQL server? How can I capture the error in a catch block and return the severity?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Here's my code snippet:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC abc 
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
/* write an insert to a table that does not exist*/ 
insert into xyz select 1
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
RAISE ERROR( 'dsd',16,1)
END CATCH
END
```

Now a missing DB object has a severity 11 according to this article :[MSDN reference SQL error severity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-error-severities?view=sql-server-2017)

So why isnt it caught? If I replace the insert with a divide by 0 scenario, the raise error that I have is being triggered. Also, how can I return the ERROR_SEVERITY() as an output parameter?

Comment: The severity is *16*, not 11. It's an invalid object name, not a missing object

Comment: Compilation errors are not the same as runtime errors. Your procedure does not compile so there is nothing it can "catch". Erland discusses this exact issue in his article on [error handling](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html)

Comment: If you run the statement you'll get `Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'xyz'.`

Comment: Note that if you do absolutely nothing to actually deal with the error, other than "return the severity", it makes much more sense to just let the error escape and make client code responsible for handling it (all client libraries have mechanisms for doing so). T-SQL's arcane rules for error handling mean it is generally a bad idea to not prepare for the case where a procedure fails to handle an error condition anyway (as it's simply not always possible), and so `TRY .. CATCH` should ideally only be used if you have actual cleanup to do as part of the procedure's own logic.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> The following types of errors are not handled by a CATCH block when
>   they occur at the same level of execution as the TRY...CATCH
>   construct:
>
> - Compile errors, such as syntax errors, that prevent a batch from
>     running.
> - Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such as object
>     name resolution **errors that occur after compilation because of
>     deferred name resolution.**
> - Object name resolution errors
>
> These errors are returned to the level that ran the batch, stored
>   procedure, or trigger.

You can't catch the non existence of a object with a `TRY...CATCH` within a stored procedure.

For example:

```
CREATE PROC TestProc AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY

        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.doesnoexists;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT ('An error occured!')
    END CATCH
END
GO

EXEC TestProc;
```

This returns the error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TestProc, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 15]
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.doesnoexists'.

You need to do the `TRY...CATCH` outside of the proc.

```
ALTER PROC TestProc AS
BEGIN


    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.doesnoexists;

END
GO
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC TestProc;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'An error occured!';
END CATCH
```

This will then print out `'An error occured!'`. Of course, instead  use `ERROR_NUMBER()`, `ERROR_MESSAGE()`, etc, to capture more details of the error that occurred and log them as you need.